# Can a Docker Task in a Swarm know which instance number or how many total instances there are?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Is it possible for a Docker Task to know which task number and how many total tasks there are running of a particular Service?

E.g. I'd like to have a Service that works on different ranges in a job queue.  The range of jobs that any one Service instance (i.e. Task) works on is dependent on the total number of Tasks and which Task the current one is.   So if it's the 5th task out of 20, then it will work on one range of jobs, but if it's the 12th task out of 20, it will work on a different range.

I'm hoping there is an DOCKER_SERVICE_TASK_NUMBER environment variable or something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this requested a few times, so you're not alone, but it's not a current feature of docker's swarm mode. Implementing this would be non-trivial because of the need to support scaling a service along with other updates to the swarm service. If you scale a service down and docker cleans up task 2 of 5 because it's on the busiest node, you're left in an odd situation where the starting count is less than the current count and there's a hole in the current numbering scheme.

If you have this requirement, then an external service discovery tool like consul or etcd may be useful. You can also try implementing your own solution taking advantage of the `tasks.$service_name` DNS entry that's available inside the container. That gives you the IP's of all the other containers providing this service just like you had with the round robin load balancer before the swarm mode VIP abstracted that away.